# How to give a 'percent watched' of dailymotion player?

Tags: javascript, progress-bar

I am developing a simple web application and I need to use Dailymotion player and upload the percentage watched each 5 seconds but I don't understand how to catch the percentage value with a event progress of this documentation: https://github.com/dailymotion/dailymotion-sdk-js

I found the next implementation: https://github.com/dailymotion/dailymotion-sdk-js/tree/master/tests. This implementation show video time in seconds but when user doing to click on the progress video bar.

Thank you

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: You could try do a math. I mean, if you have how long the video has, and how long the user alreay watched you could just do the math. Or the lib already has something to support that?